# Getting Hadoop cluster and Job Statistics

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, resources

Is there any way I can get the detailed statistics of different jobs that are alive(running), submitted, failed on my cluster? Also I want to get the **slots utilization per job and resource utilization per queue**.
Hadoop ResourceManager's Web Console already does this but I want some Tool(with better representation) or some java libraries which can derive the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://host:port/jmx to get response of the `JMX` (of corresponding resource) in JSON format.

If you want job related statistics use: http://:50030/jmx (in Hadoop 1, I am not sure about Hadoop 2).

Comment: Thanks. Any options other than REST apis?

Comment: @shubham chaurasia since hadoop exposes its metrics via JMX, you can try using jconsole kind of tools.if you are developing  your own application use JMX client library.